# How to keep information for a longer time

Tags: python

I want to make a program that takes user  input ( maybe a user's name or birthday)  and saves it somwhere so that it can be reused even after the program restarts

I've searched Google and all I get is to use a variable but variables don't keep stuff when the program terminates

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it to a file, or a database. Common methods include:

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

or JSON databases

```
import json
with open('database.json', 'w+') as file:
    json.dump(my_dictionary_or_list, file)
```

You can use similar methods to retrieve the data later. Just google "python read from file" or "python open json file" and learn how to use the method of your choice.

*Note*: This is not a comprehensive list. There are many other techniques (CSV files, the `pickle` module, sql databases, or the `shelf/shelves?` module to name a few) I suggest you start with `.txt` files and JSON, but you should slowly try to learn more because they were each built for a specific purpose and can be easier/harder than one another to implement depending on the situation.